# Как преобразовать list из list элементов в list из матриц этих list элементов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

есть list такого вида:

```
[[585, 671, 2, 588, 143, 144, 1394, 880, 411, 743, 1106, 472, 31, 1398, 33, 34, 1398, 36, 37, 38, 613, 614, 588, 143, 144, 1394, 880, 411, 743, 1106, 472, 31, 1398, 33, 34, 1398, 36, 37, 38], [410, 40, 743, 1403, 43, 917, 1106, 46, 285, 286, 1398, 467, 342, 52, 53, 54, 55]...` Как преобразовать  этот list в list из матриц такого вида: [[0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]...
```

где каждая матрица это матрица каждого list элемента первого list

это list в котором в качестве элементов тоже list

вот ссылка на код: http://pastebin.com/R66xCKAw

Comment: три раза перечитал вопрос, но осилить так и не смог... Как вы получаете второй список из первого??

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

?

```
= [[l] in l in lst]
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Если вас не затруднит - можете сформулировать вопрос на который вы дали ответ? В формулировке автора вопроса я его не смог осилить...

Comment: @MaxU а я и не понял ответ) С точки зрения программиста процесс создания ответа можно представить как функцию `Answer transform(Question q)` из чего следует что некоторые атрибуты пары вопрос-объект могут быть связаны или одинаковы. То есть на непонятный вопрос можно дать непонятный ответ. Например: некто задал непонятный вопрос и чего-то хочет - transform - я выдал что-то столь же непонятный ответ и хочу получить галочку. Кроме того, здесь есть и весьма позитивная сторона: автор может сказать что конкретно ему не нравиться, и весь процесс будет перезапущен

Comment: а я уже почти поверил в ваши телепатические способности ;) Галочку я вам поставить не могу, но могу поставить "+" за итеративный подход в улучшении качества вопроса... :-D